# How to pass a value to any url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to pass a string (`p=number`) to all the URL in my website

Example:

> www.abc.com/p/1/my-filename-1
>
> www.abc.com/p/2/my-new-filename-anything

This is my current code but it is not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove .php file extention
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


    # For individual page url
    #RewriteRule ^p/(.*)\.php $1.php?p=$2

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule, here we are getting digit from url and assigning it to the respective file with removed extension.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([\d]+)/([\w-]+)$ $2.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Coming Object Not Found.

Comment: where are you applying rule root or /p directory?

Comment: there is no p directory, p its just a variable I am passing through URL, so instead of www.domain.com/my-url-path.php?p=1 to **www.domain.com/p/1/my-url-path**

Comment: please try the edit! here i am assuming your php files have code to get the value of variable p.

Comment: Still not working, my php file will extract the value from p but the URL should work, your new edit is not working :(

Comment: if you use it without rules like this `my-url-path.php?p=1` is it working?

Comment: Please try the edit did you used the `RewriteEngine on` on top of the code?

Comment: Yes I did use RewriteEngine On at the top of the code

Comment: Please try it now i think you are having problem of trailing in your first rule, even if not working please try it without your first rule i.e. in whi you are ermoving `.php`

Comment: Awesome, now it works, thanks a ton for your help buddy. Really appreciate.

Comment: if find helpful you can acknowledge this as an answer by clicking check arrow beside the answer.

Comment: Abhishek, really appreciate your help, now I am stuck again, few url doesn't contain any value like p/1/, now those pages are not running because I have commented RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $2.php [NC,L], any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, you can edit the details in your question or ask new question. do mention me in comments.

Comment: Abhishek, its the same thread, you asked me to remove RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L], so RewriteRule ^p/([\d]+)/([\w-]+)$ $2.php?p=$1 [NC,L] was working, now I want both, url containing p/1/ & url without containing p/1/, can you help?

Comment: you can insert your first rule with this there  is no need to remove first rule i asked you because testing purposes it is working fine with your first rule i've tested it.

Comment: If I insert the first rule then the 2nd rule is not working and vise versa. any suggestions?

Comment: you tried my rule as per i given in answer above just copy & paste it if you haven't.

Comment: This is what again I am using

<pre><IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
 RewriteEngine On
 
 # Remove .php file extention
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $2.php [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^p/([\d]+)/([\w-]+)$ $2.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
 
</IfModule></pre>

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$` instead of this use this `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$` with trailing slash.

Comment: Like this RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $2.php [NC,L]  ?? Not working

Comment: `$1.php` instead of `$2.php`

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^p/([\d]+)/([\w-]+)$ $2.php?p=$1 [NC,L] 

Second rule is working but not first rule :(

Comment: Man! please have a debugging and testing approach it is necessary and helpful in IT industry. have some learning too http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

Comment: Abhishek, once more question, do you any idea why the url is not working for p/1/ & p/2/ its working for any other digit.

Comment: Ok, I tried my best to find why & how, anyway I will go through your given url, really appreciate your help on this. Thank you